# How to configure pgmodeler?

Tags: postgresql

I am having some troubles configuring pgmodeler, particularly the **Connections**.

I put

> Connection DB: postgres
>
> Host/Port      localhost           5432
>
> User           postgres
>
> Passwort

`Could not connect to the database. Message returned: could not connect to server: No route to host Is the server running on host "5432" (0.0.21.56) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

I think there is something wrong with my idea. However, I just looked for the required information on the first page of pgadmin after logging into. Can someone explain me how to get the connection from pgmodeler to my postgres DB?

Comment: Is your DB up and running at all?

Comment: Yes, I just use it via pgadminIII

Comment: I think the mistake concerns Host/Port...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had ran into this problem and solved changing pg_hba.conf in this line

```
local    all            postgres        password
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            password
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 password
```

changed the word ident to password. 
It worked for me!